# Округление

Tags: c++

К примеру:

```
double a = 2.12645;
std::cout.precision(2);
std::cout.setf(std::ios_base::fixed);
std::cout << a;
```

Он округляет и выводит 2.13. 
Как сделать так, чтобы он не округлял и выводил мне 2.12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно нестандартное округление (то есть отсечение), то есть два варианта - либо число сразу готовить к этому (что то вида `a = floor(a*100)/100;`, либо писать свой форматтер.

Comment: А ещё есть `boost/format.hpp`. Чмтать [здесь](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/format/doc/format.html).

Comment: А разве boost::format позволяет так округлять? Если да и знаете как, киньте ссылочку.

Comment: Поправка - это не округление. Это нижнее отсечение. Boost умеет очень многое. Но если ли там это - я  не увидел.

Но для данного случая наверно лучше создать свою функцию, которая будет просто выводить правильно отформатированное.

Но пришла ещё одна идея (нужно проверить). Если от числа отнять пол разряда, то потом стандартное округление будет работать правильно. То есть, последнюю строку нужно заменить на

    std::cout << (a - 0.005);

Но сразу скажу, что это не всегда будет работать - в некоторых случаях применяется хитрое округление. 2.5 -> 2, 3.5 -> 4, 4.5 ->4.

Comment: @KoVadim для случая `a > 0`?

Comment: а для отрицательных - добавить.